# How to choose items automatically in an interactive shell command?

Tags: bash, debian, automake

I know I can use `printf` to automate parameter entry for some programs.

For example:

```
printf 'user_name\npassword' | sudo openconnect URL
```

But this does not work for `npm create qwik@latest`. Because it has a step that is option selection.

I know I can provide `-y` for `npm` to suppress its confirmation message. But I know that Qwik does not have [non-interactive CLI yet](https://github.com/BuilderIO/qwik/issues/2059).

Is there any way that I can automate this command? I'm using debian 11 bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can only pipe or redirect into programs that read from standard input.  If an application does not read from standard input, anything sent there is ignored.

It is rather common for tools and programs that do not read from stdin to provide some other input method for the purposes of automation, such as for instance a batch file for `lftp`- a program's documentation would have details on such options if they exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, their documentation does not have details about this. How can I know they read stdin?

Comment: Absent documentation, the next options would be to investigate the source code yourself, or see if you can send an inquiry to the author/maintainer of the program in question.